# Get user id for delete and update selected user

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I'm trying to create admin form which can perform user creation, update and delete from frontend, See attached [image: Screenshot]
i'm trying to update user from update button but i'm little confuse how to get id for that perticular user in this list, There are also column for ID but actually i can't understand the flow of this process. If anyone has idea than please share, Thanks in advance.

This is the code

```
<?php
  /*
  Plugin Name: Test Plugin
  */
    
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_dealer_scripts');
    function ajax_dealer_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax_dealer_scripts');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'js/ajax-dealers.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_register_script( "house_doctor_inventory_script", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/ajax-dealers.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax_dealers_localize_scripts', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    }
    
    add_shortcode('ajax_dealers', 'boxer_ajax_operations'); 
    function boxer_ajax_operations($userlevel = 'all', $show_fullname = true) { 
        global $wpdb;
        global $current_user, $wp_roles;
    
        $user_info = get_users( array( 'role__in' => array( 'standard_dealer', 'special_dealer' ) ) );
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($user_info);
        // exit();
        ?>
        <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ( $user_info as $dealer ) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $dealer->ID; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dealer->display_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dealer->user_email; ?></td>
                        <td width="10%"><button class="button" id="update-dealer">Update</button></td>
                        <td width="10%"><button class="button" id="delete-dealer">Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                ?>
            <tbody>
        </table>
    
        <form id="update-dealer-form" style="display:none">
            <label for="dealerUserName">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="dealerUser_name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
            <label for="dealerEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="dealerEmail">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btn-update-dealer">
        </form>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery(document).on("click","#update-dealer", function() {
                    jQuery("#update-dealer-form").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One approach I often use is have a `<form>` for each row. You can have a hidden input in that row wit the user ID and let the buttons submit the form.

Comment: I'd normally add a data attribute to each button like `<button class="button" id="update-dealer" data-uid="<?php echo $dealer->ID; ?>">` and then on click grab that attribute with `var dealer_id = $( this ).attr( 'data-uid' );` - now when you run your AJAX, which in turn executes your PHP to update the user profile, you have the User ID as a variable to pass along to the PHP which you can get using `$_POST( 'dealer_id' )`.  If you had included your AJAX or I'd have posted this as an answer.